# AWS Lambda Function can't connect (timeout) to a FTP Server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ftp

I'm using **NodeJS** and the **basic-ftp** library to connect a FTP server but received timeout error. Local environment works perfectly.

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.x.xx.xx:21 (control socket)",
  "trace": [
    "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.x.xx.xx:21",
    "    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you configure the Lambda function to run in a VPC? Is the FTP server in your AWS account or somewhere else?

Comment: Tried within (all traffic allowed) and without VPC. FTP is outside AWS environment.

Comment: If it's not working with the Lambda function configured to run without a VPC, then the FTP server may be blocking all traffic from AWS. If that is the case, you would need to reach out to the FTP server's maintainer.

Comment: I guess it's a public FTP server but this is a good point. I'll try to check it. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkB, your point make me think and I realize that FTP server is public but in a specific country only, so i need to create my lambda func in appropriate region. Thank you again!